# Updating column on user input flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making a chat program and need to update a column of widgets of chatBubble with user input. But I am unable to do that because of immutable widgets of flutter. What can i do?

Comment: please provide you're code

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a new Stateful Widget for column :

```
class Chat extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
 _ChatState createState() => _LoginState();
}
class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Column(children://your Widget's list
  )}
```

And the update your widget's list by using setState() inside your function. Then this column will be redrawn with the new widgets' list.

Example :

```
void changeChat(newWidget){
setState((){
  //append the newWidget to your list of widgets.
})}
```